# Higher order functional approach to short circuit the execution and execute block of code if disjunction has right value

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have following `def`.

```
def withAuthorized[T,U](t:T)(func: T => U) : U = func(t)
```

Usage of it is

```
 withAuthorized(methodReturningDisjunction){ res : \/[Throwable,Boolean] => 
    res match{
      case \/-(r) => { block of code }
      case -\/(e) => e.left 
    }
```

where `methodReturningDisjunction` returns `\/[Throwable,Boolean]`

I want to abstract out `res` pattern matching logic into `withAuthorized` method such that it'll accept block of code and execute only if first `def` (`methodReturningDisjunction`) returns `right` side of `disjunction`. I am wondering what modifications will have to made to `withAuthorized` to make it function that way?

Comment: Would `def withAuthorized[E,T,U](res:\/[E,T])(func: T => U) : U = res.map(func)` be all you need?

Comment: Sorry, the return type on that should be `\/[E,U]`, not simply `U`

Comment: @Shadowlands : you're right. thanks much. that's what I needed.

Comment: @Shadowlands please put as answer so it can be accepted and other don't land here unnecessarily.

Comment: @DanielL. Sure - glad I could help.

Comment: thanks! now for @user2066049 to accept it and we are clean :-)  It is hard to look for "unanswered questions" otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the map method on `\/`:

```
def withAuthorized[E,T,U](res:\/[E,T])(func: T => U) : \/[E,U] = res.map(func)
```